# Excel VBA SQL multi JOIN, Multi file types

Tags: sql, excel, vba, adodb

I've looked for awhile now and have found some useful tips for formatting but I still can't get my code to work. It works when I remove the second `JOIN` but gives a Parameter error with the second `JOIN` added.

My code is:

```vb
Sub MultiJoinQuery()
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim csvPath As String
    Dim xlsxPath As String
    Dim con As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim i As Long

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    csvPath = "C:\Users\Me\"
    xlsxPath = "C:\Users\Somewhere Else\Book1.xlsx"

    con = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & xlsxPath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;"";"

    strSQL = "SELECT * " _
       & "FROM ([Sheet1$] a " _
       & "LEFT JOIN [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=Yes;DATABASE=" & csvPath & "].users.csv b ON a.[Name]=b.[full_name]) " _
       & "LEFT JOIN [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=Yes;DATABASE=" & csvPath & "].enrollments.csv c ON c.[user_id]=b.[user_id] "


    rs.Open strSQL, con, 3, 3


    For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        Cells(1, i + 1).value = rs.Fields(i).Name
    Next
    Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

    ''Tidy up
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

With parentheses I get [image: Param Error]

Without parentheses, I get [image]

Why do I keep getting a Param error? How can I make this code work?

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: this line seems strange [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=Yes;DATABASE=" & csvPath & "].users.csv. shouldnt be [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=Yes;DATABASE=" & csvPath & "users.csv"]. and the same for the other join.

Comment: Edited my post.
I'm pretty sure that line is correct, because it works just fine with one join.

Comment: Perhaps drop the unnecessary parentheses. I can't imagine why it wouldn't work with them in there though.

Comment: When I do that, i get a syntax error.

Comment: try `LEFT JOIN ({your subquery}) b ON a.Name=b.full_name` - I don't think *these* parentheses are unnecessary.

Comment: Please show or post the header rows of both CSVs. You may be misspelling column names. If you have MS Access, try running exact query (with hard-coded paths) in a Query Design window. Tell us what column is prompted for you to enter data.

Comment: Tried moving parentheses, receive a syntax error in FROM clause.

Checked header names, they match. I don't have MS Access.

Comment: Have you tried doing this with PowerQuery (/Get & Transform) instead?

Comment: I have not, I've never used PowerQuery.

Comment: When you do, you'll wonder why it took so long to try it!

Comment: That works well. Thanks